# Qtableview operations on filtered sets

Tags: qt

I have a working Qtableview with custom model subclassed QAbstractTableModel and QAbstractItemModel.

I have a Qlineedit, onclicked it will filter the view:

// model.cpp
setFilter(QString strFilter) function searches trough my intern QList (this Qlist is actually attached to model) and if match found then: m_filterSet.insert(i);

This all works great. Problem is, i have CRUD operations for the tableview (insert row, delete row..) which also work great! But when selecting a row from a *filtered* set, i need to somehow know where in my QList exactly is this selected row from the filtered set (QSet ).

`ui.myView->selectionModel()->currentIndex().row();`

obvious gives the wrong indexes counting for the current view.

How can i somehow extract the value (int) from the selected row in the QSet?
Because when i added this function to model:

```
foreach (const int &value, m_filterSet)
        qDebug() << value;
```

It has printed out successfully all the i values, e.g: 3410, 3411, 3412 (those are my client id's)

If i could extract this ID for the selected row in Qset, i could write a function that iterates my intern QList, and find a matching, so to speak:

```
if(m_Intern[i].nClientID == nId){   // nId = value inside Qset for selected row in view
    return nIdx;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Qt has a solution for your problem - just use `QSortFilterProxyModel`. You will need to:

- Subclass it and write your own filtering function (`filterAccpetsRow`)
- Proxy your original model through filtering one
- Attach filtering model to a view
- use [`QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#mapToSource) to convert between indexes in filtered and original model.

This allows you to have more than one view with just one source data model, each view may have different filters.

Comment: Do you need to use mapToSource() on each and every call to `currentIndex()` in the original view code or is there a more clever way to map the index?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after a while re thinking, i just needed to implement another function inside my model:

```
int myClass::screenIndex2DataIndex(int nIdxScreen)
{
   if(m_bUseFilter)
    {
        int nIdx =-1;
        for(int i=0;i<m_lstIntern.size();i++)
        {
            if(m_filterSet.contains(i))
            {
                nIdx++;
                if(nIdx == nIdxScreen){
                    return i;   
                }
            }
        }
        return -1; //not found
    }
    else{
        return nIdxScreen;
    }
}
```

This way i can find out for the present index on the filtered view, where it is in my intern list.

After this it's easy to get my nClientID trough a return: return m_lstIntern[idx].nClientId

Comment: That's going through on average half your list comparing for every index lookup. If you don't want to go the QSortFilterProxyModel route, you could populate a QMap<int,int> when you're building your filtered set that maps filtered index to unfiltered index. I guess the need depends on how often this function needs to be called.

Comment: you'r right, however i'm new to model-view programming and Qt overall, since this is just my 2nd bigger project working in C++/Qt and don't have the time to invest in research. However, my implementation works, solves the problem and on 4000 rows in a view, filtering to some items added to the end i haven't noticed any delay, it'r rather instant. Thanks buddy i already gave you up point. Should i check your awnser as accepted or not then?

Comment: QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource sounds better and has benefits. But i can't go backwards now, need pushing forward..